# Admin form placeholder won't show

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, custom, custom-field

I dug up the "stack" and found one good example of how to add new attribute to the field but it won't work.

```
    $founderFieldset->addType('text', 'Amber_SupaSlid_Block_Adminhtml_Text');
    $founderFieldset->addField('founder_name', 'text', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('vendors')->__('Founder Name'),
        'required'  => true,
        'class'     => 'required-entry',
        'name'      => 'founder_name',
        'placeholder' => $this->__('Blah blah...')
    ));
```

in this case I got blank page (just navbar and title).
In case I use:

```
    $founderFieldset->addType('text', 
    $fieldset->addType('text', Mage::getConfig()->getBlockClassName('supaslid/adminhtml_text'));
    );
```

Error 500 ....
I forgot to mention that there is no errors in logs as well :) the only error I can see it console log where it deffinitely saying there is a code problem (500) so I assume the "renderer" does not work regardless it's position/location which is correct, class name as well.